# Original Source for Norbert Wiener quote "A pattern is essentially an arrangement..." ?

Tags: math-history, pattern-recognition

I found this quote blow supposedly said by Norbert Wiener in at least two books : "Digital image processing"  by R. Gonzales and "Pattern Formation and Pattern Recognition — An Attempt at a Synthesis" by H. Haken, but found no indication on where this was registered, or if it even was said by the mathematician.

> "A pattern is essentially an arrangement. It is characterized by the
>   order of the elements of which it is made, rather than by the intrinsic nature of these elements."

Can anyone confirm or provide proof that he actually said/wrote it ?

Comment: I dk. But I know that he wrote an autobiography "I Am A Mathematician", which I have not read. Perhaps that's  a place to look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is in Wiener's book ["The Human Use of Human Beings: Cybernetics and Society"](https://books.google.ca/books?id=QqwgAAAAMAAJ), page 3.